Pulumi not using service account even though I set it as in official tutorial
I have set my GCP service account keys as instructed in this tutorial:
pulumi --config-file stacks/Pulumi.dev-core.yaml \
   -s dev-core config \
   set gcp:credentials ./stacks/dec.sa-pulumi-dev-keys.json    

This maps to a service account with GCP role Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter,
which should allow me to set secrets using KMS, example:
pulumi config set --path stack:data.test-foo-bar --secret “testvalue” --config-file stacks/Pulumi.dev-core.yaml

but I get error:
error: secrets (code=PermissionDenied): rpc error: code = PermissionDenied 
desc = Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToDecrypt' 
denied on resource 'projects/example/locations/global/keyRings/example/cryptoKeys/my-key' 
(or it may not exist).

I have double checked the resource path and it does exist in GCP.
Also this is how my config file looks like:
config:
  gcp:credentials: ./stacks/dec.sa-dev-pulumi-keys.json # file is gitignored must be downloaded from lastpass
  gcp:impersonateServiceAccount: my-sa@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com

If I set service account keys via following command:
export GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS=$(cat stacks/dec.sa-dev-pulumi-keys.json)  

Then I can run set secret command without issues:
# now it works
pulumi config set --path stack:data.test-foo-bar --secret “testvalue” --config-file stacks/Pulumi.dev-core.yaml

But doing this is not scalable for multiple stacks and environments. Why doesn't the initial command work?:
pulumi --config-file stacks/Pulumi.dev-core.yaml \
   -s dev-core config \
   set gcp:credentials ./stacks/dec.sa-pulumi-dev-keys.json    


Unfortunately, as of May 2024 there's no fix for it the only workaround it to use GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS as per pulumi's own documentation
export GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS=$(cat credentials.json)

# or 

FILE_PATH="relative/path/my-keys.json"
export GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS=$(cat $FILE_PATH)


Here is the github issue and answer from pulumi maintainer recommending to use GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS since this is not fixed: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-gcp/issues/989#issuecomment-2090906460
